# lookup RACF user data with JNDI

Tags: java, ldap, jndi, racf

I am developing a java program and need to read user data from RACF using the LDAP interface of the RACF. I establish a connection using the Java Naming Directory Interface but if I send a search request by

```
    ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
    SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
    searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=*)(racfid=test123))";
    NamingEnumeration results = ctx.search(SEARCH_BASE, searchFilter, searchControls);
```

The server receives the request but it just returns the following errorcode:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 80 - ICH31005I NO ENTRIES MEET SEARCH CRITERIA]; Remaining name: 'CN=RACFSYSA,O=IBM,C=US'
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3061)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2963)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2770)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(LdapCtx.java:1824)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(LdapCtx.java:1747)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(ComponentDirContext.java:380)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:350)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:333)
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(Unknown Source)
```

If I perform this search for a "real" LDAP Directory it works fine.
The errorcode is the default code and due to that not helpful for me.
Does anyone has an idea how to solve this problem? Is there another way to get the data of a user?

Answer (score 1):

Your search filter is not supported by LDAP SDBM 
cf http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.zos.r12.glpa200%2Fglpa2ab077.htm

String searchFilter = "(racfid=test123" would be correct

Comment: Would that be a correct filter?
String searchFilter = "(racfid=test123)";
If not what would be a correct filter?